# Filtering array based on another array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter arr1, with respect to arr2
what I am trying to achieve is, get all objects of arr1 where it's corresponding "genre" property in arr2 is "true"

```
const arr1=[
  {
    "id":1,"genre":["horror","drama","mystery"]
  },
   {
    "id":2,"genre":["romance"]
  },
   {
    "id":3,"genre":["adventure","drama"]
  },
]

const arr2=[
  {
    "genre":"horror",
    "checked":false
  },
  {
    "genre":"drama",
    "checked":true
  },
  {
    "genre":"mystery",
    "checked":false
  },
  {
    "genre":"romance",
    "checked":false
  },
  {
    "genre":"adventure",
    "checked":true
  }
]
```

so the desired output would be:

```
[
 {
   "id":1,"genre":["horror","drama","mystery"]
  },
{
    "id":3,"genre":["adventure","drama"]
  },
]
```

I have tried some configurations the javascript filter methods but i just can't think of something that works as described. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

Use `.filter` on first array and `.some` on the other array to determine if it is `checked` and element of first array contains target `genre` using `.indexOf` or even better `.includes`

```js
const arr1=[
  {
    "id":1,"genre":["horror","drama","mystery"]
  },
   {
    "id":2,"genre":["romance"]
  },
   {
    "id":3,"genre":["adventure","drama"]
  },
]

const arr2=[
  {
    "genre":"horror",
    "checked":false
  },
  {
    "genre":"drama",
    "checked":true
  },
  {
    "genre":"mystery",
    "checked":false
  },
  {
    "genre":"romance",
    "checked":false
  },
  {
    "genre":"adventure",
    "checked":true
  }
]

const result = arr1.filter(a1 => arr2.some(a2 => a2.checked && a1.genre.includes(a2.genre)))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I never knew about the `some` function in JS! No more .filter().length, yes!

Comment: Would if I could (not op) ;) Looks like OP saw it too though, as it as been accepted!